# How to use CSCore.Streams.FadeInOut

Tags: c#, audio, fading, cscore

I want to use the class [CSCore.Streams.FadeInOut](https://cscore.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#CSCore/Streams/FadeInOut.cs), which is contained in the [CSCore-Library](https://cscore.codeplex.com/). I want to fade in and fade out the songs I play. But I don't know how to use it. Does anybody know?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you already mentioned, you can use the FadeInOut-class. Checkout this example:

```
    IWaveSource source = CodecFactory.Instance.GetCodec(@"C:\Temp\test.mp3");
    using (var fadeInOut = new FadeInOut(source, 1.0f))
    {
        using (var soundOut = new WasapiOut())
        {
            soundOut.Initialize(fadeInOut.ToWaveSource());
            soundOut.Play();

            Thread.Sleep(1000);

            fadeInOut.StartFading(2, 0.0f); //reduce the volume to 0.0f over 2 seconds

            Thread.Sleep(3000);

            fadeInOut.StopFading(); //stop fading
            fadeInOut.StartFading(2, 1.0f); //fade the volume to 1.0f over 2 seconds

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

Comment: is that right, that fadeInOut.ToWaveSource() needs a parameter?
Can I write: soundOut.Initialize(fadeInOut.ToWaveSource(fadeInOut.WaveFormat.BitsPerSample));
instead, or is this bullshit?